# SQL Month Year datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Its really frustrating whenever I have to work with date/ datetime datatypes and SQL doesn't provide a good and easy way to work with it.

Currently I have this table `RecordsDaily` with a column `Date` with datatype `date`. I want to convert the `Date` column to month and take only distinct month values AND then sort according to month. Below is the query.

```
select distinct(CAST(DATEPART(year,Date) as varchar(10)) + ' ' + datename(MONTH,Date)) Month
from P98.dbo.RecordsDaily
where Date >= '2013/12/1'
order by Month
```

Obviously since I have made it `varchar` it doesn't consider it as `date` datatype and sorts it alphabetically as below.

```
Month

2013 December
2014 April
2014 February
2014 January
2014 March
2014 May
```

Any help to make it sort as per calendar.

**UPDATE**
Please note the output should be with Month and Year

Comment: What about the year? Why you select year?

Comment: Yes I need year also, so that Dec 2013 and Dec 2014 can be distinguished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
select Month from(
    select distinct(CAST(DATEPART(year,Date) as varchar(10)) + ' ' + datename(MONTH,Date)) Month
        ,year(Date) yr, month(Date) mn
    from P98.dbo.RecordsDaily
    where Date >= '2013/12/1'
)x
order by yr, mn
```

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
select * from table order by cast(('01'+id) as datetime)asc
```

-- id is your column_name